# Creating a Dockerfile for a multi-project .NET Core solution

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile

I have created a .NET 7 Minimal API solution which has four different projects within it. Below is the general structure of the project:

```
SampleProject
|_SampleProject.Application
|_SampleProject.DataAccess
|_SampleProject.Domain
|_SampleProject.MinimalAPI
    |_Dockerfile <--  Dockerfile sits inside the MinimalAPI project
SampleProject.sln
```

I am having issues trying to build everything into a single Dockerfile.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .
RUN dotnet build -c Release --no-restore

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /app/SampleProject.MinimalAPI
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/SampleProject.MinimalAPI/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleProject.MinimalAPI.dll"]
```

Using the above returns the following errors:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c dotnet build -c Release --no-restore" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

//

The type or namespace name 'Application' does not exist in the namespace 'SampleProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/SampleProject.MinimalAPI.csproj]

The type or namespace name 'DataAccess' does not exist in the namespace 'SampleProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/SampleProject.MinimalAPI.csproj]

The type or namespace name 'Domain' does not exist in the namespace 'SampleProject' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/app/SampleProject.MinimalAPI.csproj]
```

How do I resolve this and get the Dockerfile to acknowledge the other projects?